# Typescript error: Property 'localStorage' does not exist on type 'Global'

Tags: typescript, nativescript

Typescript nerds I have this code:

```
import * as appSettings from 'application-settings';

try {
    //  shim the 'localStorage' API with application settings module 
    global.localStorage = {
        getItem(key: string) {
            return appSettings.getString(key);
        },
        setItem(key: string, value: string) {
            return appSettings.setString(key, value); 
        }
    }

    application.start({ moduleName: 'main-page' });
}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

…VScode is giving me the error `[ts] Property 'localStorage' does not exist on type 'Global'. [2339]` Ideas on how to fix this?

This is a Nativescript app. For reference here is the entire file/app: https://github.com/burkeholland/nativescript-todo/blob/master/app/app.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's expected with TypeScript, the `global` typings do not include `localStorage` so it just tries to let you know it's an invalid property.

You could simply overcome the error by casting it to any.

```
(<any>global).localStorage = {
    getItem(key: string) {
        return appSettings.getString(key);
    },
    setItem(key: string, value: string) {
        return appSettings.setString(key, value); 
    }
}
```

Or you may even extend the `global` typings from `references.d.ts` that is usually located in your project root. You may create one if doesn't exists.

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        localStorage: { getItem: (key: string) => any; setItem: (key: string, value: string) => any; };
    }
}
```